# iTunes reject. App crash on launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect

I have tested my app on real devices (iPhone 4, 5, 6 (iOS 9.3.5), iPhone 6 (iOS 10.0.2)) it worked fine. Also I have tested it via TestFlight and crashlytics and it worked fine too.
I have added all needed permisions to .plist file.
[image]

But iTunes rejects my app with "Crash on launch" error.
Here is the iTunes error log.

```
  {"app_name":"MyTaxi","timestamp":"2016-09-30 13:32:23.72 -0700","app_version":"3.3.2","slice_uuid":"831c101e-38b5-3eb5-b796-fc5063aa4168","adam_id":0,"build_version":"1.7","bundleID":"com.uznewmax.mytaxi","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.0.2 (14A456)","incident_id":"F490701B-6F47-4367-81D9-6972158B379A","name":"MyTaxi"}
Incident Identifier: F490701B-6F47-4367-81D9-6972158B379A
CrashReporter Key:   c17abe71a5696611be627fa0e17aaf62664e40c0
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             MyTaxi [1000]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E25A1977-5FE0-4E45-ABFA-D765D41F2FEA/MyTaxi.app/MyTaxi
Identifier:          com.uznewmax.mytaxi
Version:             1.7 (3.3.2)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.uznewmax.mytaxi [737]


Date/Time:           2016-09-30 13:32:23.5674 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-09-30 13:32:18.1792 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.0.2 (14A456)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x18fbf41c0 0x18e62c55c 0x18fbfb278 0x18fbf8078 0x18faf259c 0x1000c8d5c 0x18ea7d1c0 0x18ea7dfb4 0x1000c7500 0x1000c8e58 0x195aa837c 0x195cb8b70 0x195cbe8e0 0x195cd3080 0x195cbb8c4 0x1917958bc 0x191795728 0x191795ad0 0x18fba2278 0x18fba1bc0 0x18fb9f7c0 0x18face048 0x195aa15dc 0x195a9c360 0x1000b92b0 0x18eab05b8)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ebc2014 0x18eba3000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec89460 0x18ec84000 + 21600
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018eb363f4 0x18ead3000 + 406516
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018e6012d4 0x18e600000 + 4820
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018e61ecc0 0x18e600000 + 126144
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018e62c844 0x18e624000 + 34884
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018e61b66c 0x18e600000 + 112236
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018e61b6dc 0x18e600000 + 112348
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018e62c7a0 0x18e624000 + 34720
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ea7d1d4 0x18ea7c000 + 4564
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018ea7dfb4 0x18ea7c000 + 8116
11  MyTaxi                          0x00000001000c7500 0x100094000 + 210176
12  MyTaxi                          0x00000001000c8e58 0x100094000 + 216664
13  UIKit                           0x0000000195aa837c 0x195a26000 + 533372
14  UIKit                           0x0000000195cb8b70 0x195a26000 + 2698096
15  UIKit                           0x0000000195cbe8e0 0x195a26000 + 2722016
16  UIKit                           0x0000000195cd3080 0x195a26000 + 2805888
17  UIKit                           0x0000000195cbb8c4 0x195a26000 + 2709700
18  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001917958bc 0x19175b000 + 239804
19  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000191795728 0x19175b000 + 239400
20  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000191795ad0 0x19175b000 + 240336
21  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fba2278 0x18fac5000 + 905848
22  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fba1bc0 0x18fac5000 + 904128
23  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fb9f7c0 0x18fac5000 + 894912
24  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018face048 0x18fac5000 + 36936
25  UIKit                           0x0000000195aa15dc 0x195a26000 + 505308
26  UIKit                           0x0000000195a9c360 0x195a26000 + 484192
27  MyTaxi                          0x00000001000b92b0 0x100094000 + 152240
28  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018eab05b8 0x18eaac000 + 17848

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ebc2a88 0x18eba3000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec8536c 0x18ec84000 + 4972
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec84db4 0x18ec84000 + 3508

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ebc2a88 0x18eba3000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec8536c 0x18ec84000 + 4972
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec84db4 0x18ec84000 + 3508

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018ebc2a88 0x18eba3000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec85188 0x18ec84000 + 4488
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec84db4 0x18ec84000 + 3508

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec84db0 0x18ec84000 + 3504

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eba416c 0x18eba3000 + 4460
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eba3fdc 0x18eba3000 + 4060
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fba1cec 0x18fac5000 + 904428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fb9f908 0x18fac5000 + 895240
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018face048 0x18fac5000 + 36936
5   Foundation                      0x00000001905dcb1c 0x1905d0000 + 51996
6   Foundation                      0x00000001905fd60c 0x1905d0000 + 185868
7   UIKit                           0x0000000196416c7c 0x195a26000 + 10423420
8   Foundation                      0x00000001906da50c 0x1905d0000 + 1090828
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec87860 0x18ec84000 + 14432
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec87770 0x18ec84000 + 14192
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec84dbc 0x18ec84000 + 3516

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eba416c 0x18eba3000 + 4460
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eba3fdc 0x18eba3000 + 4060
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fba1cec 0x18fac5000 + 904428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fb9f908 0x18fac5000 + 895240
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018face048 0x18fac5000 + 36936
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001902bbcec 0x1901ef000 + 838892
6   Foundation                      0x00000001906da50c 0x1905d0000 + 1090828
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec87860 0x18ec84000 + 14432
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec87770 0x18ec84000 + 14192
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec84dbc 0x18ec84000 + 3516

Thread 7 name:  GAIThread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eba416c 0x18eba3000 + 4460
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eba3fdc 0x18eba3000 + 4060
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fba1cec 0x18fac5000 + 904428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fb9f908 0x18fac5000 + 895240
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018face048 0x18fac5000 + 36936
5   Foundation                      0x00000001905dcb1c 0x1905d0000 + 51996
6   Foundation                      0x00000001906312a0 0x1905d0000 + 397984
7   MyTaxi                          0x000000010050bff4 0x100094000 + 4685812
8   Foundation                      0x00000001906da50c 0x1905d0000 + 1090828
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec87860 0x18ec84000 + 14432
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec87770 0x18ec84000 + 14192
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec84dbc 0x18ec84000 + 3516

Thread 8 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eba416c 0x18eba3000 + 4460
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eba3fdc 0x18eba3000 + 4060
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fba1cec 0x18fac5000 + 904428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fb9f908 0x18fac5000 + 895240
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018face048 0x18fac5000 + 36936
5   AVFAudio                        0x00000001a8c52fe8 0x1a8bda000 + 495592
6   AVFAudio                        0x00000001a8c78f14 0x1a8bda000 + 651028
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec87860 0x18ec84000 + 14432
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec87770 0x18ec84000 + 14192
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec84dbc 0x18ec84000 + 3516

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eba416c 0x18eba3000 + 4460
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018eba3fdc 0x18eba3000 + 4060
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fba1cec 0x18fac5000 + 904428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018fb9f908 0x18fac5000 + 895240
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018face048 0x18fac5000 + 36936
5   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000192b46fd0 0x19298f000 + 1802192
6   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000192d1c590 0x19298f000 + 3724688
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec87860 0x18ec84000 + 14432
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec87770 0x18ec84000 + 14192
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018ec84dbc 0x18ec84000 + 3516

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001700f5db7
    x4: 0x000000018e61fbc3   x5: 0x000000016fd69de0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000000000000b  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x000000018eb4d792  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000030000000300  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b421ac40  x21: 0x000000016fd69de0  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000178048b80
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x00000001965633b9  x26: 0x0000000196568b6d  x27: 0x0000000100d02960
   x28: 0x00000000000000d8   fp: 0x000000016fd69d40   lr: 0x000000018ec89460
    sp: 0x000000016fd69d20   pc: 0x000000018ebc2014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: You will need to [symbolize](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) your crash log, this will tell you more about your crash. Like which line in which method.

Comment: Does your app need an internet connection? Have you tried running it in airplane mode to make sure thats not causing issues?

Comment: Make sure you installed a clean (release) build on your device and try to repo it first

Comment: @Flexicoder Yes my app needs internet, and I've tried to install it while device is in airplane mode. It runs normal.

Comment: @Itachi Yes, I 've installed on clean device. I also tried to install it from xCode, after clean project, clean build folder. It works fine.

Comment: @Arthur Try the tool symbolicatercrash

Comment: @Itachi I have resolved the problem. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem and I've resolved it.
The problem was in AFNetworking and IPv6. Now, Apple requires IPv6, and tests all app with IPv6.
My app works with AFNetworking, and it was setup for IPv4 (AFNetworkReachabilityManager)
I've resolved my problem by changing `AF_INET` to `AF_INET6` in `AFNetworkReachabilityManager.m`

```
+ (instancetype)sharedManager {
    static AFNetworkReachabilityManager *_sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        struct sockaddr_in address;
        bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
        address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
        address.sin_family = AF_INET6;

        _sharedManager = [self managerForAddress:&address];
    });

    return _sharedManager;
}
```

Hope it will help somebody.